# Firestore pagination by offset

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create two queries, with pagination option. On the first one I would like to get the first ten records and the second one I would like to get the other all records:

```
.startAt(0)
.limit(10)

.startAt(9)
.limit(null)
```

Can anyone confirm that above code is correct for both condition?

Comment: Are you getting any error message while using this ?

Comment: No, I didn't test it yet. Just want to sure that cursor position starts from 0 at startAt and also to pass null to limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore does not support index or offset based pagination.  Your query will not work with these values.

Please read the [documentation on pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) carefully.  Pagination requires that you provide a document reference (or field values in that document) that defines the next page to query.  This means that your pagination will typically start at the beginning of the query results, then progress through them using the last document you see in the prior page.

Comment: Hi Doug, while I was researching on the same topic, I found the below document that shows an example of using offset in firestore admin to skip documents: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#offset. Do I understand correctly that it's already available and wondering if it's ok to use it? I guess I saw somewhere that offset will still read through each document first to calculate the "starting" document resulting in additional charges and that it's advised to use a DocumentSnapshot to paginate anyway. Appreciate your input on this.

Comment: Doug, the order by field should be unique, other wise we will miss some records, 
Consider data is `A A A A B B B B`, and first query is `limit(3)`, and next page is `startAfter(A).limit(3)`, we missed 4th `A`

Comment: that mean we cannot build generic things because Snapshot is based on Firebase Model. That's stupid, we cannot because of that replace easily a backend by an other

Answer (score 2):

From [CollectionReference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#offset):

```
offset(offset) → {Query}
```

Specifies the offset of the returned results.

Comment: @pawello2222 thanks for making my response more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

As Doug mentioned, Firestore does not support Index/offset - BUT you can get *similar* effects using combinations of what it *does* support.

Firestore has it's own internal sort order (usually the document.id), but any query can be sorted .orderBy(), and the first document will be relative to that sorting - only an orderBy() query has a real concept of a "0" position.

Firestore also allows you to limit the number of documents returned .limit(n)

.endAt(), .endBefore(), .startAt(), .startBefore() all need *either* an object of the same fields as the orderBy, *or* a DocumentSnapshot - *NOT* an index

what *I* would do is create a Query:

```
const MyOrderedQuery = FirebaseInstance.collection().orderBy()
```

Then first execute

```
MyOrderedQuery.limit(n).get()
```

or

```
MyOrderedQuery.limit(n).get().onSnapshot()
```

which will return one way or the other a QuerySnapshot, which will contain an array of the DocumentSnapshots.  Let's save that array

```
let ArrayOfDocumentSnapshots = QuerySnapshot.docs;
```

> Warning Will Robinson!  javascript settings is usually by reference,
> and even with spread operator pretty shallow - make sure your code *actually*
> copies the full deep structure or that the reference is kept around!

Then to get the "rest" of the documents as you ask above, I would do:

```
MyOrderedQuery.startAfter(ArrayOfDocumentSnapshots[n-1]).get()
```

or

```
MyOrderedQuery.startAfter(ArrayOfDocumentSnapshots[n-1]).onSnapshot()
```

which will start AFTER the last returned document snapshot of the FIRST query. Note the re-use of the MyOrderedQuery

You can get something like a "pagination" by saving the ordered Query as above, then repeatedly use the returned Snapshot and the original query

```
MyOrderedQuery.startAfter(ArrayOfDocumentSnapshots[n-1]).limit(n).get() // page forward
MyOrderedQuery.endBefore(ArrayOfDocumentSnapshots[0]).limit(n).get() // page back
```

This does make *your* state management more complex - you have to hold onto the ordered Query, *and* the last returned QuerySnapshot - but hey, now you're paginating.

## BIG NOTE

This is *not* terribly efficient - setting up a listener is fairly "expensive" for Firestore, so you don't want to do it often.  Depending on your document size(s), you *may* want to "listen" to larger sections of your collections, and handle more of the paging locally (Redux or whatever) - Firestore Documentation indicates you want your listeners around at least 30 seconds for efficiency.  For some applications, even pages of 10 can be efficient; for others you may need 500 or more stored locally and paged in smaller chucks.